# Can't find Reverse Engineer Code First in Solution Explorer after installing ProPowerTools.vsix

Tags: frameworks, entity

After installing the ProPowerTools.vsix for Visual Studio 2012, I'm not able to find the 
Reverse Engineer option in Solution Explorer when I right click on the project > EntityFramework menu option.

I have installed the EF5.0 via NuGet.

Comment: Have you restarted Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I restarted VS, still don`t see it.

Comment: Sorry, was in the limbo... I mixedup EFPowerTools with ProPowerTools I had downloaded 2 days before. Sorry.  Now working